# brownie.exceptions.RPCRequestError: Web3 is not connected

Tags: brownie

I am trying to deploy a helloWorld.sol using brownie. I am getting below error when I tried to run ***brownie run scripts/deploy.py***.

> Terminating local RPC client... Exception in thread Thread-5:
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 175, in _new_conn
> (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
> line 96, in create_connection
> raise err   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
> line 86, in create_connection
> sock.connect(sa) ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 706, in urlopen
> chunked=chunked,   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 394, in _make_request
> conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 239, in request
> super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in
> _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in
> endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in
> _send_output
> self.send(msg)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
> self.connect()   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 205, in connect
> conn = self._new_conn()   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 187, in _new_conn
> self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
> <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021DAA2A0F28>:
> Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 449, in send
> timeout=timeout   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 756, in urlopen
> method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]   File
> "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
> line 574, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1',
> port=8545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x0000021DAA2A0F28>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py",
> line 82, in _request
> response = web3.provider.make_request(method, args)  # type: ignore   File
> "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\providers\rpc.py",
> line 91, in make_request
> **self.get_request_kwargs()   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3_utils\request.py",
> line 48, in make_post_request
> response = session.post(endpoint_uri, data=data, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 590, in post
> return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)   File
> "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 542, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 655, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 516, in send
> raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8545): Max retries exceeded
> with url: / (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x0000021DAA2A0F28>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No  connection could be made because the target machine
> actively refused it'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\state.py",
> line 332, in *add_to_undo_buffer
>
> self.sleep(0)   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\state.py",
> line 375, in sleep
> self.*time_offset = int(rpc.Rpc().sleep(seconds))   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc_*init**.py",
> line 45, in wrapped
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc_*init**.py",
> line 166, in sleep
> return self.backend.sleep(seconds)   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py",
> line 91, in sleep
> return _request("evm_increaseTime", [seconds])   File "C:\Users\mmasn.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\ganache.py",
> line 86, in _request
> raise RPCRequestError("Web3 is not connected.") brownie.exceptions.RPCRequestError: Web3 is not connected.

My deploy.py code is below.

```
from brownie import accounts, HelloWorld


def deployHelloWorld():
    account = accounts[0]
    helloWorldObject = HelloWorld.deploy({"from": account})
    helloWorldObject.setName("Michael", {"from": account})
    greeting = helloWorldObject.sayHello()
    print(greeting)


def main():
    deployHelloWorld()
```

could you please help?

Answer (score 6):

This error is caused because there is no waiting after transaction. By using `transaction.wait(1)`, as below, the problem is fixed.

```
transaction = helloWorldObject.setName("Michael", {"from": account})
    transaction.wait(1)
    greeting = helloWorldObject.sayHello()
    print(greeting)
```

Answer (score 4):

RPC is sometimes killed too quick, resulting in brownie.exceptions.RPCRequestError: Web3 is not connected.
Therefore you have to add the time.sleep(1) after every transaction to ensure your code runs smoothly.

Comment: Wouldn't this potentially slow down the script, wouldn't it be better to catch an exception?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put after transactions

```
transactionVariable.wait(1) 
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.